# Get system language in ISO 639 (3-letter codes) in Python

Tags: python

Could someone tell me a way to get a system language in the [ISO 639 (3 letter code)](http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/IG/ert/iso639.htm) format in a cross platform way?

Thanks.

I found a [list](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#BpbMiH2xT_E/pub/FreeBSD/distfiles/hachoir-core-0.9.0.tar.gz|RzjpTZgjwM0/hachoir-core-0.9.0/hachoir_core/iso639.py&q=iso%20639%20lang:python) of three letter country codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're wanting [ISO 639 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2) and not [ISO 639 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-3) here. Machine-readable data is available from the [Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/ISO-639-2_utf-8.txt) (I'm using the "utf-8" encoding for this answer, see also http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/ascii_8bits.html for more info.)

Here's an example of how you could load this:

```
import codecs

def getisocodes_dict(data_path):
    # Provide a map from ISO code (both bibliographic and terminologic)
    # in ISO 639-2 to a dict with the two letter ISO 639-2 codes (alpha2)
    # English and french names
    #
    # "bibliographic" iso codes are derived from English word for the language
    # "terminologic" iso codes are derived from the pronunciation in the target 
    # language (if different to the bibliographic code)

    D = {}
    f = codecs.open(data_path, 'rb', 'utf-8')
    for line in f:
        iD = {}
        iD['bibliographic'], iD['terminologic'], iD['alpha2'], \
            iD['english'], iD['french'] = line.strip().split('|')
        D[iD['bibliographic']] = iD

        if iD['terminologic']:
            D[iD['terminologic']] = iD

        if iD['alpha2']:
            D[iD['alpha2']] = iD

        for k in iD:
            # Assign `None` when columns not available from the data
            iD[k] = iD[k] or None
    f.close()
    return D

if __name__ == '__main__':
    D = getisocodes_dict('ISO-639-2_utf-8.txt')
    print D['eng']
    print D['fr']

    # Print my current locale
    import locale
    print D[locale.getdefaultlocale()[0].split('_')[0].lower()]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `pycountry` at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry/ which seems to have the ISO 639 2 codes (just using google :-)

Comment: I did look up PyCountry but it seems to be dependent on `lxml` and I didn't want to use another library for a small trivial task. I did find a list of three letter codes. (Look at my modified post)

Comment: How could i get the system language though? I could then try and figure out the three letter code for it. Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale (gives `('en_AU', 'cp932')` on my PC so I'll modify the above example to accept ISO 639 2 codes as well) I think some linux distros might use ISO 639 3 nowadays, but don't quote me on that - just thought I'd warn you though

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/KnowledgeBase/StartingTeam - it looks like Ubuntu uses the `ISO 639-1` two letter first, the `ISO 639-2` and then `ISO 639-3` if one isn't available (probably not very common languages though)

Comment: (sorry, that should've been `accept ISO 639-1 2-letter codes` two comments ago)

Comment: For the record: `pycountry` seems to have removed the dependency of `lxml`.